# package org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector does not exist

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I'm trying to work with Hive UDF's and UDAF's and so far, I've managed quite well in doing so using maven from the command line on a VM that has essentially been set up quite well by someone very knowledgable. I'm new to Java (projects, not so much the language) but I can at least see what my current issue is. What I don't know is why it's happening and how to fix it.

So...

my problem is that for whatever reason, when running

```
mvn install
```

the compiler can't find any classes past

```
/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec
```

It can find all classes in the 'exec' folder, but nothing in any subfolders nested in 'exec'. I don't understand why this is the case. Here is my POM file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.matthewrathbone.example.RawMapreduce</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.matthewrathbone.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>hive-extensions</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hive-extensions</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0-cdh4.3.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- TEST DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>cloudera</id>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

An example of one of the many errors I get is in the title. 'vector' is a folder located in `/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec`.

As far as I can tell, the `hive-exec.jar` file is listed as a dependency in my POM file, so I'm not really sure why the compiler is having trouble locating all the classes contained within it (it can find some, as mentioned previously).

Essentially what I'm trying to do is incorporate one of the built-in UDAF's as my own temporary function, so that I can bypass Hive's restrictions on sub-querying inside the 'SELECT' statement.

Comment: Are you running `com.matthewrathbone.example.RawMapreduce` from the JAR built by Maven assembly? If so, I am not sure `hive-exec` is in the assembled JAR, because the scope for the dependency to `hive-exec` is "`provided`". Try remove `<scope>provided</scope>` for this library and `hadoop-client` if this is the case.

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez, no dice on that.

Comment: I've created my own package name at the top, and when I run mvn-install that package is created in the resultant .jar file. That is, I'm using `hive-extensions-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to be more specific, I made some adjustments and eventually narrowed it down to compiler was looking for `class VectorizedUDAFs` which as it turns out, my version of `hive-exec` .jar does not have.... go figure. Thus, it couldn't find it because it actually did not exist...